# Porting existing application to mobile using Worklight / Phonegap

Tags: web-applications, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a **existing web application**. Now I want to **port** this app on **smartphones** and tablets.
As I have cross platform need so i am thinking about Worklight or Phonegap.

Instead of again making a seperate Worklight application and then deploying it on Mobile will result in rework for me which I dont want due to limited time span.

So is there any other way by which i can **port my existing web app on mobile** with less efforts?
What will be the challenges if i do so?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

A Worklight project has a certain structure to it, and there is manual work for you, to place each code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) in the correct locations.

If your application is also doing some network calls, you will need to - potentially - change these to Worklight adapters, depending if you'd like to use Worklight security features or otherwise. And other things to do, again, based on your application.

Application development is not an automated task. There will be manual work to do.

Comment: Earlier i have made a small Web Application and developing the same appliction on Worklight i did the same ,placing the js,css images etc in the specific worklight folders and refrencing it from index.html and it worked ... it was a simple application 
My actual issue was it it had Database ,network calls how can it be manged

Comment: You'll need to re-implement those using Worklight adapters.